# Karate: Runner "builder" method for generated .txt outputs

Tags: karate

Is there an existing Runner "builder" method to disable `~karate-json.txt` outputs when generating reports alongside the HTML ones?

I'm looking for that similar to `outputJunitXml(false)`.

Any help would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. Is there any reason why this is a problem ? Karate will not be able to generate the final report without it. This design is to prevent running out of memory when you run a large test-suite for a long time.

Note that Karate is open source. Maybe you can contribute code to improve this ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was just looking into how I could possibly organize further the generated report files so it's not much of a problem. Thanks for clarifying that it's needed. I will look into contributing code once I find the time. Thanks again!

Comment: @jjeoneun thank you for understanding ! also, the reason we give it a `.txt` extension is so that it does not interfere with other / CI tools that may look for `.json` and `.xml` files to generate optional reports. also note that you can choose to delete all these files using custom code after the `Runner` returns, hmm maybe we can add this option to karate, but I really don't think it is a priority - and it may be useful for debugging - and also, it can be used for advanced "retry" use-cases: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#retry-framework-experimental

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thanks for sharing that. I agree that it's quite a low priority haha I understand that there are more important issues to work on so it's okay. For now, I'll be trying it with custom code as you've suggested. Thank you for your help!